# Using Jackson (ObjectMapper) how serialize object to json and ignore all fields except the ones I annotate as @JsonProperty?

Tags: java, json, jackson, marshalling

**UPDATE:**

I was wrapping my object in another one during the response creation and that class didn't have any `@JsonProperty` annotations. Adding them to its getter methods made this work.

**Original**
I am trying to ignore all fields except the few that the class wants to keep, but I am getting an empty object (it's ignoring everything). How do i do this?

Converting the object to json string:

```
//The marshaller
ObjectMapper marshaller = new ObjectMapper();

//Make it ignore all fields unless we specify them
marshaller.setVisibility(
    new VisibilityChecker.Std(
        JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE
    )
);

//Allow empty objects
marshaller.configure( SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false );

return marshaller.writeValueAsString( myObject );
```

The object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private Integer id;
    private Event event;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Timestamp createdDate;

    public EventAction(...)
    {
        ...elided...
    }

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Event getEvent()
    {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event)
    {
        this.event = event;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedDate()
    {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Timestamp createdDate)
    {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your `@JsonProperty` to the property/field level and this should work.

Sample w/ tests to verify.

https://github.com/Flaw101/jackson-ignore-everything/tree/master

Edit,

Updated for deserialization tests too.

Comment: Does this mean it won't use my setters/getters?

Comment: No, it will use getters/setters. Jackson uses javabean convention for getters/setters. Updated the example with system outs to verify this for you.

Comment: I'm trying this and it's still coming up as an empty object

Comment: What's the rest of your setup, and Jackson version? I've been able to use `@JsonProperty` exactly as you have documented.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, it was because i was wrapping it with another class that didn't have any `@JsonProperty` annotations.

Comment: It does work on the methods. no need to put on the fields. It was just a dumb mistake on my part (See update above) Gave you an upvote for the help!